# Why Doesn't /**/* Work On Commandline on Windows

Tags: windows, closures, cygwin

I have been running a command line program (Closure compiler) in Cygwin on Windows 7 (no comment please) that takes file arguments. It used to be that, for both the program and when I typed
echo dir/**/*
it would include all subdirectories and files, regardless of how deep. Now, it only returns the directories and files on the second level. I have not changed anything. I updated Windows at one point, but I did not think that that would affect anything. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to figure out what changed or how to fix this?

Comment: I do not see how it could have worked, however why you don't use `find` or `dir -R` ?

Comment: @matzeri Because the program that I was trying to run takes either repeated file names or a wildcard for multiple files. Also, I figured out that the problem was that globstar somehow got turned off.